# Learning about Biztalk Orchestration

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-2009

I am new to BizTalk server and I am really confused with Orchestrations. Is there any site where I can learn about Orchestration in detail.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the questions that are out off topic. I will be asking for specific problem solving questions.

Comment: Don't use orchestrations unless absolutely unavoidable. They are a mess and were bolted onto BizTalk core engine for BTS2004. BizTalk is good at some things, but modelling business processes is not one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the BizTalk Tutorials.  They cover most aspects of BizTalk, including Orchestrations.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560270.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/dd849956.aspx